# What does it mean - "My family is a bunch of Baratheons"

Tags: game-of-thrones

I recently posted a picture of my wife and I at the theater to see the play WICKED. I had a beard (I don't know if that's relevant).

My brother commented, "My family is a bunch of Baratheons"

Since I don't watch Game of Thrones...I know, I know...but what is he referring to? What is that supposed to mean?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the picture, but it sounds like he was probably commenting on your appearance. The Baratheons do have pretty full beards in the show, especially Robert Baratheon.

Comment: I wasn't sure if it had to do with the beard or not. But you're leaning to believe it did?

Comment: Without any other context, yes. They are also known for their dark hair. The family sigil is the stag and they are a royal family, if any of that helps clear it up.

Comment: @DKu You've shined some light on this for me. Thank you. (We all have dark hair too)

Comment: This question has very little to do with Movies & TV, however. It's merely a comparison with a related subject, and adds nothing to it. I flagged it as off-topic.

Comment: This is only tangentially a question about Game of Thrones.  This would be more suitable for the site chatroom.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A major plot point in early seasons of Game Of Thrones was the idea that when a member of the Baratheon family had a child, that child always had thick black or dark brown hair, regardless of the hair colour of the other parent.

So the comment would make extra sense if you, your brother, at least one parent and any children, nieces or nephews have dark hair, while your other parent, wife and/or other parents of nieces or nephews do not.

It might also just be the resemblance - especially if one of you is large and wild and the other svelt and fashionable, while both dark haired and bearded. Here are two typical-looking Baratheons, Robert and Renly:

[image]

Source: http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/29600000/Robert-and-Renly-house-baratheon-29677793-1066-696.png

There's one other possibility worth mentioning (or, warning about...) - if you look like the young man above at the rear (Renly), and your brother looks like this stern Baratheon below... watch your back, and beware of shadows.

The night is dark and full of terrors.

[image]

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stannis_Baratheon

Comment: Good answer. The Baratheon's don't seem to have a clearly defining attribute of their house in the same way as the Lannisters, Starks, Greyjoys and others.  (Aside from the black hair!;)

Comment: @DukeZhou black hair, and (at least in the books) height.  All three of them are huge in the books, that doesn't translate to the actors chosen for the show.

Comment: @kuhl Good point--they are all tall!